Driving a transformer with an AC to AC converter
I have a variable inductor which operates at a 60Hz frequency this goes to a control board that takes this variable voltage and applies it to a high voltage transformer. I want to control the output on the high voltage transformer and figured I could use an AC to AC converter to replace the variable inductor. If I have a micro controller or PLC control the firing of the SCR`s in the converter and add an isolation transformer I should be able to drive the high power transformer just fine. Am I correct in this assumption or is there something I am missing? My thought is the chopped up waveform should still drive the step up transformer just fine.


Also this is really just for experimental purposes " High voltage" is 220 VAC it is not really high voltage at all but being this is an educational lab and we are instructing people who have little experience we call it high voltage to make them more aware.

Why not use a variac?

The variac is not providing the precise control and repeatability that is required for this application. From the drawing you can see I am using a variac already.

A motorized variac with feedback and regulation? A programmable AC source?

My thought was the power semi-conductors would be the more economical solution. The motorized variacs are something that I would have to get on my hands and knees to beg for. This well is cheap and theoretically should get the job done.

Also this is to test the silicone on lab made wafers so while the chemistry is different the voltage must be heald within tolerance a motorized variac well may work but there is the maintenance issues and the size requirements it needs to be relatively small to match what is already there

EMI could be the issue here - if you are using this to "test the silicone on lab made wafers" then I suspect very sensitive measurements are being made.  An SCR or transistor-based circuit creating a "chopped up waveform" could generate so much noise that it affects the measurements.  We need more information about your application and the circuits & systems surrounding this "variable inductor controlled high-voltage transformer".  What is the output voltage range at the output of this high voltage transformer?

I will ask to see if I can share that I should be able to tax payers paid for it.

Using an SCR 'chop' drive will add a lot of harmonics to the waveform. If your goal is to have a known AC voltage profile, those harmonics will make this impossible to control: you could have some unwanted extra-high-voltage spikes in it. Not what you want in a test source.
Instead, I suggest using an audio amplifier fed with a sine wave to drive the transformer primary. Then you have fine control over the amplitude with low distortion.
Class D modules are inexpensive and provide astonishing power levels for their size (example.) Since you're driving a transformer, you could use a stereo pair in bridge config to drive the transformer. Then use your favorite signal gen to make the source (could be a PC audio jack, etc.)
